# A RESTful api, multiple types of user access problems?

Tags: java, restful-url

A RESTful api, multiple types of user access problems? Api as follows:

`/ articles / 1 get` It's means that getting an article;

```
/**
 * 获得文章
 *
 * @param authorId
 * @param articleId
 * @return
 */
@GetMapping("/articles/{articleId}")
public ArticleEntity getArticle(@CurrentAuthor AuthorEntity author,
                                @PathVariable("articleId") Integer articleId) {
    // get one article for author
    ArticleEntity article = articleService.get(author.getId(), articleId);
    // get one article for visitor
    // ArtilceEntity article = articleVisitorService.get(articleId);
    return article;
}
```

For article viewers, you can only get articles that have a status of published.
For the author of the article, you can get a variety of status (draft, published, recyclable) article.

In the program I used the custom annotation @Authorization and the Spring MVC interceptor to specify which controller methods are logged in to access, obviously this method is not suitable for this way.

1. If you use the above api, how to distinguish between the request which belongs to the user?
2. For this api, how to use login authentication?
3. If the design is unreasonable api, then please give me some suggestions?

thank you very much!

Comment: Since REST services usually are stateless, for login you'll need to use a token or a structure that can carry the user id. [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is an option.

Comment: Use spring security. It should solve all issues.